# Getting Navigation Props in Custom React Navigation Title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom title in my (simple) React Navigation StackNavigator, looks like this:

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitle: <GradientHeader title={this.state.navigation.title} />
  }
});
```

But this returns `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.navigation')`

How can I pass the views' unique titles to the custom header?

Answer (score 0):

per the docs, you need to give `navigationOptions` as function to access `navigation`:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
       headerTitle: <GradientHeader title={navigation.state.params.title} />,
    }),
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm passing a component, not just the title.

Comment: it still says undefined... could it make a difference that I'm in the Stack, not the individual screen?

Comment: You may need to set `initialRouteParams` as well

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work for every screen, but I got it to work on just the home screen

Comment: to get it to work on every screen, your `navigation.navigate()` calls would need to be passing a `{ title: 'screen name' }` param